# For an Azure Key Vault, is it possible that within a single keyvault different secrets are used to access different resources (yes/no)? If yes, how?

Tags: azure-keyvault

For an Azure Key Vault, is it possible that within a single keyvault different secrets are used to access different resources? If yes, how?

Comment: What do you mean use the secret to access resources? Could you elaborate on your scenario?

Comment: Is it possible for different secrets to access different resources within a single keyvault?

Comment: Azure Key Vault is provided to store secrets.

Comment: Yes, I know that, the secret is also an azure resource, what do you mean use a resource to access another resource? Could you give a specific sample?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/secure-your-key-vault

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal

Comment: I know all of these docs, so actually what do you want?

Comment: Just asking question only.

Comment: I am not so sure what to give a specific sample.

Comment: I suppose you want to use the secrets in different resources? i.e. use different resources to access secrets? e.g. the code runs in web app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As conveyed in the comments, Key Vault is simply a repository for storing keys, certificates and secret values. You can use the [role-based access control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/rbac-guide) functionality to limit what applications and users are able to access what resources, but apart from the [hard limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#key-vault-limits) imposed on the Key Vault instance, you've got quite the large quota of secrets you're able to store within a single Key Vault.

In practice, there's no charge for spinning up multiple key vaults, so you might put all your secrets in one vault, all your certificates in another and all your keys in yet another, or you might drop everything into a single vault - that's entirely up to you.

No reason you can't put your access keys for each of your storage accounts in separate secrets and have an authorized Service Principal read them out for use elsewhere, or even use secrets to store the client IDs and passwords for a variety of service principals created across your tenant (e.g., no reason you can't just store JSON objects in there and leave it to your applications to parse the contents).

In short, to answer your question, absolutely. Just add the data you need to store as text in your secret, set up your application via RBAC to access your Key Vault, retrieve the secret and utilize accordingly.